# Workloads on Flux Cloud, who is accountable / responsible for any kind of content hosted on the platform?

Tags: intellectual-property, internet, data-ownership, dmca, accounting

I recently stumbled across the https://runonflux.io platform which promises to host decentralized web applications by distributing the workload among many individual locations / distributed nodes.

"The Flux Cloud is a People-Powered Network to help you build decentralized applications with increased flexibility, scalability, and censorship resistance"

As I'm not an expert in law I was asking myself, if you become part of the network and share resources, meaning hosting an own FLUX server and join it to the Cloud. How can you ensure the owned node does not infringe the law when someone is hosting bad content? I think at some point you will be responsible for all the stuff you do host behind your public IP. Unfortunately I was unable to dig deeper and have not found the answers here: https://runonflux.io/privacyPolicy

Maybe related to: [Who is responsible for copyright infringement on P2P distributed systems?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/22470/who-is-responsible-for-copyright-infringement-on-p2p-distributed-systems)